# How to get the current Request Mapping URL configured at Controller layer when request is executed?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-rest

I went through so many links like [How to show all controllers and mappings in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766800/how-to-show-all-controllers-and-mappings-in-a-view) and [How to configure a default @RestController URI prefix for all controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34801351/how-to-configure-a-default-restcontroller-uri-prefix-for-all-controllers) and so on.

I want to get the Request Mapping URL at Filter interceptor

Ex: This URL I configured at REST controller method, and naturally we will pass `/employees/employee-names/John` to get the Employee John.

```
/employees/employee-names/{employee_name}
```

Now, when somebody hit `/employees/employee-names/John` I want to get the value of actual mapping url if REST controller `/employees/employee-names/{employee_name}`,

Any pointers how to get that ?

Comment: please check it, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025872/reflectively-getting-list-of-spring-mvc-controllers-matching-specific-url

Comment: Is there any way if we can get the controller method name ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue using below code. `AntPathMatcher` is the perfect way to identify if the incoming request and URL you configured in the property file matches exactly. This solution works greatly for me.

```
AntPathMatcher springMatcher = new AntPathMatcher();
Optional<String> antMatch = props.getMapping().stream()
     .filter(//Perform Some Filter as per need)
    .map(Mapping::getVersion)
    .findFirst();
return antMatch.isPresent() ? antMatch.get() : null;
```

Answer (score 3):

Spring MVC sets the attribute `HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE`, which you can use to get the pattern that was used to match the incoming request:

`String matchingPattern = (String) request.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE)`

That would return `/employees/employee-names/{employee_name}` in your case.

Comment: This is not working for me. Best matching patterns gives null to me

Comment: @PAA: Maybe your filter is executed before the handler mapping is done and this attribute is set? Could you use a ControllerAdvice instead of a filter?

Comment: For future readers who stumble upon this answer, `((HttpServletRequest)req).getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_PATTERN_ATTRIBUTE))` works for me. But it must be used after `chain.doFilter()` when used in a filter.